# Setting up key bindings of Corsair Vengeance K70 to work with OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I recently purchased a Corsair Vengeance K70 and am trying to get set the `ctrl windows alt` keys to match the ones on a mac keyboard, `control option(alt) command`. So far I've tried setting the key bindings by going to `System Preferences -> Modifier Keys -> Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard` and testing different configurations of key settings though this appeared to have no effect. I also attempted switching the `BIOS switch` on the keyboard though that seemed to have no effect. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/screen_shot-large.gi) as it seemed to fit my needs and it made it easy to switch the keys. My only complaint is that there is not a per keyboard setting so this also affects my (less used) mac keyboard. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I just got this keyboard, and I had the same problem as you. The fix was simple, after you select the modifier keys, just save, close system preferences. Then unplug they keyboard, and reconnect it. After that it worked like a charm.